# Can I edit profile in app (android)?

Tags: feature-request, android-app

It seems I am not very good at using this app, or maybe I'm getting old (had to write something since SE don't allow me to just ask one a sentence question)

Can I edit my profile in android app? If so, how?

Comment: It's not you, it's the app. It got only some basic features, editing the profile is not one of them.